# WooCommerce, manually add a product and price for purchase

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to use the WooCommerce Cart and Checkout functionality if I need to purchase something that isn't technically a `product`

In other words, it's a completely independent "membership" that needs to be purchased, but isn't a product post.

I'd love to be able to add an item in the cart manually ... manual name, manual price, manual meta data and then purchase.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is example

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(16);
```

16 -> this is ID of existing product in store

documentation [Link](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html)